# How to get encrypted object data in Amazon S3 - SSE-CPK?

Tags: encryption, amazon-s3

I just begin Amazon S3 for my project. It has nice Server Side Encryption function.
I have used Customer Provide Key to upload/download with my own key.
It's fine. But sometime i need to get raw data (encrypted data) by request without algorithm and key.
But it response error.
So i want to firgure out a way to solve my problem.
Thanks for your help !

Comment: You need to Go Through before posting a query [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry!. This is my first post

Comment: no Problem  Dude Just Go through it and Update query accordingly which helps you to get More Views which leads to some answers .. Good Luck

Comment: Didn't get why SSE provided by Amazon doesn't work for you. Just edit your question according to the [How To Ask tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and I'll be happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Why?  If AWS exposed raw data, it could be used to break encryption.  SSE is not provided to secure data externally to AWS. Exposing raw data puts your customer's keys and data at risk of being compromised by brute force decryption techniques.

> Server-side encryption is about data encryption at rest—that is, Amazon S3 encrypts your data at the object level as it writes it to disks in its data centers and decrypts it for you when you access it.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/serv-side-encryption.html

> Caution
>
> If you lose the encryption key any GET request for an object without its encryption key will fail, and you lose the object.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerSideEncryptionCustomerKeys.html